# After my Windows 10 update (July 2018) I cannot start my Hyper V VM: Bootdisk not found

Tags: hyper-v, windows-update, uefi

I have applied some windows updates on both my host (Windows 10) and my Hyper-V guest (Windows 10). After rebooting the hyper-v VM cant boot anymore displaying the message that there is no active boot item for booting from UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

After some trail and error, the solution was to reinstall hyper-v on my windows 10 host.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that hardware virtualization support is turned on in the BIOS settings
Configure networking for the Hyper-V environment to support external network connections. Also ensure that a virtual switch has been created and is functional
Remove all security software and AV
System and drivers are up-to-date.
Also, try to use PowerShell command-line to enable Hyper-V.

```
Install-WindowsFeature –Name Hyper-V -ComputerName <computer_name> -IncludeManagementTools -Restart
```